# I need to add more view helpers when bootstrap in Zend

Tags: zend-framework

I have a application.ini which is already defined:

```
resources.view.helperPath.Core_View_Helper          = "Core/views/helpers"
```

Now I want to add more view helpers when bootstrap like:

```
$view->addHelperPath('My/View/Helper','My_View_Helper_');
```

I have tried around a lot of solutions like:

1. add a method be named: `_initView()` then
   `getResource('view')->addHelperPath()`
2. use `Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->addHelperPath()`, but this
   does not work too

Comment: post the whole bootstrap (at least anything that touches the view object) and probably most of your application.ini. Context counts in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the trailing underscore in the 2nd parameter of your call to addHelperPath.

```
$view->addHelperPath('My/View/Helper','My_View_Helper');
```